# Good mapping library to use in conjunction with AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, mapping, afnetworking

Does anyone know of a good, simple library that can be used with AFNetworking to map JSON response objects to my model objects and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about a Core Data model, there's something even better: the makers of AFNetworking now also have [AFIncrementalStore](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore), which lets you use your web service as a Core Data backend. [Read more about it here.](http://nshipster.com/nsincrementalstore/)

Comment: thanks, this looks to be the ticket! seems pretty easy to integrate too!

Answer (score 0):

I am using NSDictionary to take in the JSON responses and then using objectForKey to get the attributes, or you can just use `dict[@"AttributeName];`  See sample code for JSON request below:

```
   AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSError *jsonError = nil;
    NSDictionary *parsedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];

    id response = [parsedData objectForKey:@"response"];
    NSDictionary *responseDictionary = nil;
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        responseDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)response];
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Jastor library to map AFNetworking's responses (NSDictionaries) to my classes. Works like a charm. Take a look at: https://github.com/elado/jastor