# AFNetworking response object mapping

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am trying out AFNetworking after coming from RestKit and I am wondering if there's a simpler solution than having to do this for all of my objects:

```
- (id)initWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes {
    // ... init

    _userID = [[attributes valueForKeyPath:@"id"] integerValue];
    _username = [attributes valueForKeyPath:@"username"];
    _avatarImageURLString = [attributes valueForKeyPath:@"avatar_image.url"];

    return self;
}
```

This is how things appear in the AFNetworking basics example. But this looks like it might get cumbersome as soon as I'm returning objects with children. Is there an easier way for me to do this?

I saw that there is the AFIncrementalStore as referenced in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880785/good-mapping-library-to-use-in-conjunction-with-afnetworking). But I do not want any of the information retrieved to persist beyond the current session so I didn't think that was the right thing to do.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use RestKit?

Comment: It was really just to try AFNetworking after hearing so much about it. I'm relatively new to iOS and I've only used RestKit and wanted to see what/if I was missing out on!

Comment: But RestKit is built on top of AFNetworking so you can use both where they are most appropriate...

Comment: I see. Thanks! This is not something I'd realised. I think this answers my question then!